# How do I recalculate a field if another field was changed in a form

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

And where do I put that code? In the model or the controller? 
I was thinking in the controller update function, is that the right place?

Also, how do I know the old value of a field? The $request variable only contains the new value.

This is for creating a new password when the username is changed.

(Yes I know passwords should not be kept in cleartext in a database, but this is for provisioned devices, so there's no other way)

EDIT: An piece of example code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more item in your form as hidden value which is "id" or any unique key  of that user so you know which user we are dealing with  from that key or id with the help of query call the data of particular user 
Then check weather then name change or not if change updates new password else not 
Hope this might help you

Comment: Yes, I thought of that but I figured many users should have this problem and Laravel probably has a solution for it without spending a database query on it

Comment: you also can do that without query if you put it in validation same thing check there also